# C++ Array of Arrays, defining parts separately

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to make an array of arrays containing 2 lists of strings (one singular and one plural).

```
string item_name[2][6];
string item_name[0] = {"bag of CinnaCandies", "can of Arizona Tea", "Starbucks Mocha Frappe", "copy of Section 8: Prejudice", "Sushi Box", "pair of Nike Jordans"};
string item_name[1] = {"bags of CinnaCandies", "cans of Arizona Tea", "Starbucks Mocha Frappes", "copies of Section 8: Prejudice", "Sushi Boxes", "pairs of Nike Jordans"};
```

I don't know the proper syntax to do this and I'd like to keep it as an array of 2 arrays so I can have code that says:

```
if (quantity > 1)
    {
        cout << item_name[0][index];
    }
    else
    {
        cout << item_name[1][index];
    }
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise normally, but instead of a regular constant you use a sub-array:

```
string item_name[2][6] = {
    {"bag of CinnaCandies", "can of Arizona Tea", "Starbucks Mocha Frappe", "copy of Section 8: Prejudice", "Sushi Box", "pair of Nike Jordans"},
    {"bags of CinnaCandies", "cans of Arizona Tea", "Starbucks Mocha Frappes", "copies of Section 8: Prejudice", "Sushi Boxes", "pairs of Nike Jordans"}
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You're on the right track.  You just need a single declaration, and nest the brackets so that you have an array of arrays:

```
string item_name[2][6] = {{"bag of CinnaCandies", "can of Arizona Tea",
                           "Starbucks Mocha Frappe", "copy of Section 8: Prejudice",
                           "Sushi Box", "pair of Nike Jordans"},
                          {"bags of CinnaCandies", "cans of Arizona Tea", 
                           "Starbucks Mocha Frappes", 
                           "copies of Section 8: Prejudice", "Sushi Boxes", 
                           "pairs of Nike Jordans"}};
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers above are correct. In addition, you also can use something like this:

```
vector<string> item_name[2];
```

This way, you still have an array of "arrays" but the sub-array size is not fixed, so you can continue appending as many entries as you need.

And of course, you can also use the notation

```
item_name[0][index];
```

To get the "index" item at the first top-level array.

Comment: Thanks. I'd seen vectors but didn't know what they were. I shall go research them now.